# Can devices connect to loopback address of another device?

Tags: networking, routes, ip, ipv4

Can devices connect to loopback address of another device? The loopback address can be assigned to any IP address e.g 12.12.12.12. It's not necessarily to be 127.0.0.1

Device supports multiple loopback addresses.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/247625/what-is-the-loopback-device-and-how-do-i-use-it

Comment: Wrong info here. Loopback address can be configured on physical interface of device too.

Answer (score 1):

Other devices can connect to your loopback addresses as long as they have a route to them. For the special address range `127.0.0.0/8`, but as you say you can configure other addresses as well. I usually use the dummy interface for this.

Distributing routes can be done manually by configuring manual static routes, or with routing protocols like OSPF and BGP. There are several implementations of those for most common operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

A device can support multiple loopback interfaces (ex : Router/L3), but an interface support only one IP address . 
A loopback interface could be connected to another device or not, it depends on your configuration ... you can manage the routes of all your network manually or you can use a routing protocol if Intra-domain then you use (OSPF or RIP) or Inter-domain than you use BGP.